# coming, admittedly, after Sir Lancelot had already defeated Guinevere's accuser

Tags: word-meaning

what is the meaning of "[coming](https://gargoyles.fandom.com/wiki/Nimue)" in

> Afterwards, maybe in order to make amends to Arthur for depriving him of his magical advisor and guardian, she came to his aid on a number of occasions, twice foiling assassination attempts of Morgana le Fay's, once (with the help of Sir Tristram) rescuing Arthur from the evil sorceress Annowre, and once clearing Queen Guinevere of a poisoning charge made against her (**coming, admittedly, after Sir Lancelot had already defeated Guinevere's accuser, Sir Mador de la Porte, in a "trial-by-combat"**). She was also in the boat that came to take Arthur away to Avalon, after his final battle.

Comment: (Having looked at the link) - Nimue's action of clearing Guenevere of a poisoning charge _happened_ after Sir Lancelot had defeated her accuser - it _came after_ it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikitionary gives one of the minor senses of "come" as "happen", with this example:

> This kind of accident comes when you are careless.

This is roughly the sense here.  This participle could be paraphrased as relative clause

> clearing Queen Guinevere,  [...], which [came=happened] after Sir Lancelot had already defeated Guinevere's accuser.

And "came" means roughly the same as "happened".  So it means that she cleared Guinivere's name after Sir Lancelot had defeated her accuser.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!